# Auxin-what happens to the auxin chemicals if the Sun is just above the plant?

Tags: endocrinology, plant-anatomy, growth

The Auxins goes to the shady side for the elongation of the cell. This moves depending on the direction of sunlight. But, what happens to the auxin chemicals if the Sun is just above the plant?

Comment: Have you attempted to answer this question yourself by scouring the internet? Basically this question is a 1-liner and we encourage a bit more background and leads in a question.

Comment: Nope, There is no answer to the question. I always search it in the Net before i ask it here!

Comment: What did you find?